# Shiny: Deleting rows from data

Tags: r, shiny

How to delete rows from data in shiny?

Just assume the data

```
X
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Now I want to create new data set "Y" using a variable "X" by deleting 7, 8 and 9.
Idon't want to see 7,8 and 9 in "Y" variable.

Could you help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Y<-X[X<7]
```

that will put only the x values less than 7 into Y